# Should I switch to Python 3.5 from Python 2.7.6 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, python3, python-2.7

After I read this topic [Why upgrade to Python 3.4 from 2.7.8](https://www.quora.com/Why-upgrade-to-Python-3-4-from-2-7-8)  I decided to move to Python 3.5. While looking over "How to upgrade to Python 3.x on Linux" I stumbled upon this one: [You probably don't actually want to change your default Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256389/6063416)

Is that still true? I read that support for 2.7 will end, even though not very soon. The part that scares me the most is the one with

> and may have scripts that depend on this being present,

Comment: A word of warning: do not, I repeat, *do not* try to change the Python version globally. It will screw up your system big time.

Answer (score 1):

The two links talk about different things. The first one talks about using python 3.4 for your own scripts and project while the other one talks about upgrading your default Ubuntu python version.

Since **Python 2 and 3 can both be installed on one system** you can use python 3 for your projects without changing the system default.

I don't think it's safe switching your default Python version (from 2 to 3). And it is completely unnecessary since python 2 and 3 can run side by side.

When you have python 2 and 3 side by side, the terminal has 2 commands `python` and `python3`

Good Luck :)